# Jquery UI datatable sort only for tr's with style "display: block"

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I have a requirement to sort only the rows of a table which has a style as "display: block". In other words, sorting should not be applied for rows which has style as "display: none" using jquery UI datatable. Suggestions please.

Find below the **HTML code** of the table:

```
<table id="tbl-songs" role="grid">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Song Name</th>
<th>Song Artist</th>
<th>Song Release Date</th>
<th>Song Album Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="display: block">
<td >Love Me</td>
<td >Brittney</td>
<td >Mar 27 2015</td>
<td >Some Album</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: block">
<td >Hold Me</td>
<td >Brittney</td>
<td >Mar 27 2015</td>
<td >Some Album</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none">
<td >Hug Me</td>
<td >Brittney</td>
<td >Mar 27 2015</td>
<td >Some Album</td>
</tr>

<tr style="display: none">
<td >Kiss Me</td>
<td >Brittney</td>
<td >Mar 27 2015</td>
<td >Some Album</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Jquery code:**

```
$('#tbl-songs').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false }],
                "bFilter": false,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "aaSorting": []
            });
```

Comment: What code you have tried ? please paste here

Comment: Yeah, please provide the `HTML` code of your `table`.

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated the question by adding HTML and JQuery content.

Comment: Finally, I have found a solution for this issue. The problem can be solved by coding a call back function and inside that, we can specify the work to be done. This call back function of the datatable will be called each and everytime the sorting is done.

Comment: The sample code is as follows,

`$('#tbl-songs').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "bSortable": false }],
            "bFilter": false,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                $("#tbl-songs").append(); //Here we can append the rows which are of style display none
            }
        });`